# check the string for empty or null values in JSP?

Tags: jsp, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am working in JSP forms and i am sorting the results on the basis of user selection criteria. now the problem is in the if condition which only falls in the first condition
either the I select the city or not

My sample code is below:

```
if (user_city !=null || user_city !="") 
{  
  out.print("first condition is true"); 
}
else 
{
  out.print("second condition is true");
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `||` when you probably want `&&`. In your original code, if `user_city` is null, it will try the second comparison, where `null != ""` is true. This makes the whole thing true, which seems contrary to your intention. It would also be good to take the other advice and make the comparison:

```
if(user_city != null && !user_city.trim().isEmpty()) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim `user_city` before checking with empty string

```
if (user_city != null && !"".equals(user_city.trim())) {
    out.print("user_city is not null and not empty");
} else {
    out.print("user_city is either null or empty");
}
```